# iis6 crashes for unknown reason

Tags: iis-6, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a problem where IIS6 becomes unresponsive (page cannot be displayed) for some unknown reason.  The app that everyone uses from this sits inside the default web site using a different app pool.  So trying to access http://[servername]/ or http://[servername]/app/ results in the same thing  I have tried the following:

- Restarting IIS (iisreset)
- Restarting the app pools

Restarting the server appears to be the only cure.

I can only assume there is an issue with the service which the www process runs with (svchost - correct me if I am wrong) but I have no idea what it could be.

A little bit to help understand the situation

- Virtual server sitting on VMWare
- Windows server 2003 R2
- Almost fully patched!

This doesn't happen on a frequent basis (every day) but does look like it happens at least once a week.  Do let me know if you want to know a bit about the app sitting on IIS and I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to resolve this one myself.  One of the apps on the server (separate to IIS used a library which had a dependency on .Net 3.5 and it looks like there was an issue with sp1.  I re-wrote the code to use a different library that had no dependency on 3.5 :)